# Is it allowed to camp outside the designated fields in Portugal?

Tags: camping, portugal

Me and my friends are planning a road trip to Portugal in August. We would like to hire a camper for 4 people and cruise along the coast, and do some surfing.

That said I read that camping is prohibited except for designated camping areas - it is allowed to park the car by a road, but not to camp. This is quite understandable for the safety reasons, however I was wondering about camping at some "unspoilt by human /wild" terrains (and not national parks), preferably close to the oceanside.

We will obviosuly keep it safe, and clean- but would love to avoid busy campings, and stay as close to nature as possible.
Does anyone here know if the Portugese are strict about giving tickets to those who want to camp outside of designated camping fields?

Comment: Yes, I meant sleeping inside the vehicle, but also cooking inside the hevicle and e.g having chairs outside of hehicle. We obviously wouldn't do it by the road (for safety reasons), but if we find "a wild place" a bit away from work, I was wondering if we could camp there ?

Answer (score 4):

When this question was asked, it was legally allowed - even if often frowned upon -, but later it was specifically banned by the [decree 102-B/2020](https://dre.pt/home/-/dre/150757538/details/maximized), which went into effect in January 2021, and which forbids staying inside a camper or similar from 9 pm to 7 am, except when parked on a designated camping field.

Answer (score 1):

After the COVID-19 crisis there are many people having the same idea, trying to escape the crowded spaces and going to the wilderness, close to the ocean. This tendency is even being news in media these days ([here](https://www.publico.pt/2020/03/16/local/noticia/autocaravanas-estrangeiras-invadem-alentejo-ja-ha-blocos-betao-fronteira-serpa-1908027) and [here](https://tvi24.iol.pt/videos/sociedade/autocaravanas-invadem-estacionamentos-das-praias-no-litoral-alentejano/5ecc13e90cf2634381ae843a)).
Authorities are on the field to avoid this situation to go out of control and passing fines.

So, sorry, I have to tell you that it's not a safe option.